# Clojure. list of keywords to dict

Tags: clojure, zipmap

Could you please tell me how can I make the dict form the list?

E.g. I have the list [3 4 5] and :value keyword.

I need to create the following dict:

`{{:constant_keyword "constant", :value 5 }  {:constant_keyword "constant", :value 4} {:constant_keyword "constant", :value 3}}`?

I know how to make a constant value:

```
(def const-dict (take (count [my-list]) (repeat {:column "type"})))
```

But I do not know who to do it with a parameter like the item of an array:

(take (count [my_list]) :value) - doesn't work, I can't create list of keywords and then zipmap it to another list.

How can I do it?

Comment: that hash map isn't valid - perhaps you wanted a list or vector of hash-maps?

Comment: Can't use just do something like `(map #(assoc {:const "const"} :value %) [1 2 3])`?

Comment: or like this: `(map (partial hash-map :const "const" :value) [1 2 3])`

Comment: Thanks, it's so easy. I do not understand why I have failed to write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(map #(assoc {:constant_keyword "constant"} :value %) [3 4 5])
```